# How to hide asterisk(*) for required tag field for Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, validation

Please help me how to hide or remove the asterisk(*) for required tag field (added in select tag, it will display as required field) in Lightning component form

```html
<lightning:select aura:id="job2" value="{!v.shows[1].Function__c}" onchange="{!c.handleOnChange2}" name="job2" required = "true" messageWhenValueMissing = "This field is required.">
```

Comment: Why would you want a required field not to be marked as required in the UI? That's usually considered a hostile UX experience.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `required` attribute and validate the form when it is submitted.

Comment: Required is mandatory when you use <lightning:select> for showing the error message

Comment: Then don't use that attribute. Display the message elsewhere on your page after you validate the form data when it gets submitted.

Comment: For picklist values, I need to use that attribute!!

Comment: Then you can't remove it either of them. What you could do is implement your own select component then.

Comment: Please check here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223055/lightninginput-mandatory-true-not-fired-on-button-click/223057?noredirect=1#comment527482_223057

Comment: We cant use either if we can use <lightning:select>. That is my question, what is solution?

Comment: Lets get in-depth for lightning: select . It has "required" attribute. How does it work? Well to answer, it works on value change. When your component is loaded first time, there is no value change and thats why even if the default value is null, it won't indicate user to input it.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/specification

According to lightning:select documentation, we have showHelpMessageIfInvalid() method which will give user the error message if the input provided by him is invalid. In our case required.
Similary, we have "validity" attribute present in lightning:select which we can use to find if the values are valid.